# jwplayer seek() and onTime() to play bits of video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, jwplayer

So I've been trying to manipulate my jwplayer which plays youtube videos with success but still encounter a bit of a problem.

I want my player to play from a "start time" and stop at en "end time". Those two values will be taken from two form inputs. So I went and wrote this little function which work quite well :

```
function timeControl(start, end) {
jwplayer().seek(start).onTime(function (event) {
    if(event.position >= end ) {
        this.stop();
    }
});

}
```

The thing is, if I run this function twice, the second time it will sometimes ignore the new parameters (for example if I set the start time at 3 seconds and end time at ten, if I run it again with the end time being 6seconds, it will work, but it won't if I start with end time at 6 and then at ten... )

Anybody has an idea of what's going on ? Anyway to reset the "onTime" property of the player without having to reload the player ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I'm going to out on a limb and say that the problem simply might be that your generically referencing jwplayer, and not specifically referencing a jwplayer video instance.

```
<div id="aVideoObject">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jwplayer("aVideoObject").setup({
        flashplayer: "player.swf",
        width: 450,
        height: 320
    });

    function timeControl(start, end) {
        jwplayer("aVideoObject").seek(start).onTime(function (event) {
            if(event.position >= end ) {
                this.stop();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This implementation works for me

Comment: They might have changed the API to let you do that now, but there was no way to cancel an event listener on the fly on an instance back then. I remember not being the only one looking for that... In any case, I had only one player on the page so it shouldn't change anything referencing globally or specifically. If I remember well we had to destroy the player and reinstantiate it every time for it to work. Anyway I use video.js now and it's awesome :)

Answer (score -1):

You can find START time and duration here:

[JW_Player_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jieyunfu/mediaplayer/JW%20Player%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.pdf) [[Mirror2](https://github.com/mehulved/jwplayer-example/raw/master/jwplayer/JW%20Player%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.pdf)]